# Writing python factorial function using recursion

Tags: python, recursion, factorial

I am new to Python, I am trying to write a Python program to calculate and print factorials up to n! as shown ***using recursion***.

[image: desired result]

However, I only get the following result:

[image: Current result]

Here is my code right now:

```
def factorial( n ):
    print("n n!")
    if n <=1: 
        print(str(n) + ' ' + str(n))
        return 1
    else:
        r = n * factorial( n - 1 ) 
        print(str(n) + ' ' + str(r))
        return r
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: Sorry, it is only a typo and I edited it

Comment: So your question is now the opposite of what it once was? You are going to have a hard time in school if you are this loose with the details...

Comment: Well, then there's nothing wrong, except that you forgot to "write a program" and instead used the interactive interpreter. Write a script instead.

Comment: Thanks, @Wooble. I figured out the correct code with your hints.

Answer (score 1):

With recursion:

`factorial = lambda n: n * factorial(n - 1) if (n > 1) else 1`

This is similar to your function, except I don't print things out (because it slows it down and is unnecessary).

If you try to evaluate it, with, for example, the number 4:

```
factorial 4
4 * factorial(4 - 1)
4 * (3 * factorial(3 - 1))
4 * (3 * (2 * factorial(2 - 1)))
4 * (3 * (2 * 1)))
24
```

What this does is take the number `n`, then checks if it is greater than 1. If so, it returns `n` * the factorial of `n - 1`. If it is less than or equal to 1, then it returns 1.

Comment: Maybe a few explaining sentences would be helpful... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured out what is the problem. I used the Python Interactive Shell to run the program, so resulting in double printing of final result.

I put the program in a .py file and run it using command line and I finally got the correct result.

The code finally becomes:

```
def factorial( n ):
    if n <=1:   # base case
        print(str(n) + ' ' + str(n))
        return 1
    else:
        r = n * factorial( n - 1 )  # recursive call
        print(str(n) + ' ' + str(r))
        return r

print("n n!")
factorial(9)
```

Answer (score -1):

Without recursion:

```
def factorial(n):
    answer = 1
    for i in range(2, n+1):
        answer *= i
    return answer
```

With recursion:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n<=1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*factorial(n-1)
```